# match and remove the string in given string from the Array of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have input like

```
x = "+91458888888"
```

and to match with given array of country code is `y = ["+91","+92","+923","+912"]`

output should be `z = "458888888"` and `z1 = "+91"` else `false`,

i don't know what is first step to proceed with this question, any help and suggestion. thank you

Comment: The first step would be to find the location of every string in `y` in `x`. And if it's `=== 0`, then do the rest. You might use `String.prototype.indexOf`. So, you need to iterate over `y` and `indexOf` `x` against every item in `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var z;
var y = ["+91","+92","+923","+912"];
var x = "+91458888888";

// Sort based on length
y.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.length - b.length;
});

y.forEach(code => {
  if(x.indexOf(code) >= 0)
    z = x.replace(code , '')
});

console.log(z)
```

Comment: its failing in this case y = ["+1","+1684"] , x= "+168402443432424" expected output '02443432424', but your code resut is '68402443432424'

Comment: @HemanthSP What is the expected output in the above case? (I got answer as "02443432424") And how do you determine which country code it is in this case? If there is a logic then I might be able to help

Comment: y = ["+1684","+1"] this case?  expected output '02443432424', but your code resut is '68402443432424'

Comment: @HemanthSP I have updated the answer to sort the array based on length before processing. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible avoid the '+' sign from your array items, this will make the solution alot eassier.

Step 1: sort the array in descending order, it will eliminate the chance to get partial matching

Step 2: Form the regex and match

Step 3: return result

```
var data = [91,92,923,912];
data.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
var match = new RegExp('^\\+('+y.join("|")+')(.*)?$');
var ph = "+95458888888".match(match);
if(ph) {
  //return ph[2]
  console.log(ph[2]);
} else {
  //return false;
}
```

If you can't change the structure of Array y, you can convert your array to the given format using map method or via iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var x = "+91458888888"
var reg = /\+(91|92|923|912)(.*)/
if(reg.test(x)){
  var number = x.match(reg)[2];
}else{
  //false
}
```

Comment: i  have country code more than 200 like list var reg =[+91,+43............]

Answer (score 0):

if the number length (without country code) was fixed, the simplest way:

```
let x = "+91458888888";
const result = x.substr(x.length - 9); // '9' was length of the real nubmer 
console.log(result);
```

otherwise use the regex like other anwsers.

Answer (score -1):

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modvbu

```js
var data = ["+1684","+92","+923","+912"];
var match = "+168402443432424";

let count=-1;
var finalOutput;

  if (data.some(v => { return match.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
        data.some(v => { 
        count=count+1;
        if(match.indexOf(v) >= 0)
        {
           finalOutput = match.replace(data[count],''); 
           return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
       });
  }
 
console.log(finalOutput);
```

Comment: data.some(fun.. line throwing error in angular 4 error TS2345: Argument of type '(v: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => boolean'.  
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. is this possible to arrow function ?

Comment: is this possible to add arrow function ?  data.some(function(v) { 
        count=count+1;  ......here is the issues..